# fill imageview fully to linearlayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview

This is what I want my ImageView to look like :

[image: improper behaviour]

What my ImageView is looking like in emulator :

[image: improper image]

I tried playing with `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and  `android:adjustViewBounds="true"`
but it is still not working.

My full XML layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.resizedimage.Imgmain"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try scaleType = "fitxy"

Comment: but it is changing the aspect ratio

Comment: set `android:layout_height="0dp"` to LinearLayout and  `scaleType = "fitxy"` to ImageView.

Comment: bro image is gone now

Comment: @KaranMer Try my answer code. Its working fine!

Answer (score 1):

change scale type from fitcenter to fitxy

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Comment: its doing the task but aspect ratio is changing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:background="@drawable/img"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            />
```

or

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:background="@drawable/img"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
                />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.resizedimage.Imgmain"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:    
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">        
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>     
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/img"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.resizedimage.Imgmain"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/images"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```